# Create screenshot after failed selenium command

Tags: selenium, phpunit

The PHPUnit Selenium base class has an option to make a screenshot on failure, which is a huge help in finding out why the test failed. The selenium server, however, returns an error instead of a failure on any error condition other than explicit `assert*` calls (such us trying to do something with a non-existent element). If I try to make a screenshot after the server reports the error, I get another error saying that the server already discarded the session. Is there any way to change that behavior?

**Update:** this is because PHPUnit breaks the connection when it receives an error. I was able to change it by some (rather ugly) manipulation of the PHPUnit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the Selenium server but the `SeleniumTestCase` class for PHPUnit 3.4 which automatically sends a stop command when it detects an error (Driver.php line 921). PHPUnit 3.6 seems handle errors better.

Answer (score 1):

Make those interactions as test cases.

For example in perl,
If it is written as below and fails due to a non-existent element. the script will ***error*** out

```
$sel->type("email-id","trial\@trial.com");
```

While if the above step is made as a test case by writing it as follows

```
$sel->type_ok("email-id","trial\@trial.com");
```

If there is a non-existent element, the test case will only ***fail***, and the script will continue.

So using TAP (test any protocol) by using the module `use Test::More;` , if `_ok` is added after a function, the function return will be used to determine the fate of the test case.

ie. - A return of 'O' means the test *Failed*

and A return of '1' means the test *Passed*

Comment: `<cmd>_ok` is just a wrapper in Test::Www::Selenium which will call `<cmd>` and then handle the return value somehow. That does not help; as soon as `<cmd>` is called, the selenium server drops the session, and I am unable to get the screenshot.

Comment: Strike that; it seems PHPUnit is the one dropping the session.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can overwrite method 'travelbox' and make something like this:

```
public function onNotSuccessfulTest(Exception $e){
       file_put_content('/xxx/xxx.jpg', $this->currentScreenshot());
 }
```